# SQL bulk Insert not saving all rows in database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am importing excel data in to SQl Server using SQL Bulkcopy. It is working good on my local system (It is saving over 80,000 rows at a time.).
But when I upload it on web it is not able to save all rows in database.
I am using following code:

```
SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "BrucknerData";
bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add(7, "Customer");
bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add(28, "InvoiceDate");
bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add(27, "InvoiceNo");
bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add(23, "CustomerPo");
bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add(26, "SoLine");
bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add(11, "VendorName");
bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add(12, "Category");
bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add(13, "Item");
bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add(17, "PickQty");
bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add(18, "Price");
bulkInsert.ColumnMappings.Add(19, "PriceExtention");
con.Open();
bulkInsert.BulkCopyTimeout = 3600;
bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
con.Close();
```

Please help me resolve it.

Comment: is it throwing any error? what it exactly mean `on web it is not able to save all rows in database`

Comment: No error message...  Web means.. when i upload it on domain

Answer (score 0):

refer this code.

```
 if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" || FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel")
            {
                if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength >= 0)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                    string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadControl.FileName);

                    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/DownloadedExcelFilesOp4/myfile" + fileExt));
                    if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength == 0)
                    {
                        lblMsg.Text = fun.UploadStatus;
                        lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                    else
                        lblMsg.Text = fun.UploadStatus;
                    lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=YES;IMEX=1'", Server.MapPath(@"~\DownloadedExcelFilesOp4\myfile" + fileExt));// + "\\" + FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName.ToString());
                    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
                    {
                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(("Select [Customer] ,[InvoiceDate] , [InvoiceNo] , [CustomerPo],[SoLine] ,[VendorName] ,[Category] ,[Item] ,[PickQty] ,[Price] ,[PriceExtentio]  FROM [Sheet1$]"), connection);
                        connection.Open();
                        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString))
                            {
                                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TempExamQuation4Master";
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Customer", "Customer");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("InvoiceDate", "InvoiceDate");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("InvoiceNo", "InvoiceNo");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CustomerPo", "CustomerPo");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SoLine", "SoLine");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("VendorName", "VendorName");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Categor", "Categor");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Item", "Item");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PickQty", "PickQty");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Price", "Price");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PriceExtentio", "PriceExtentio");

                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```